# Map Language for OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good afternoon.
I decided to switch to the OpenLayers platform for creating maps on the site.
Tell me, please, is it possible to set the English language as a single language for all signatures of geographical objects on the map.
Sincerely, Alex.

I looked in the documentation but didn't find it.

Comment: Could you explain, a little more, what you mean by geographical objects?